# Как настроить TabLayout, чтобы вкладки растягивались на весь экран?

Tags: android, tab

Подскажите, как можно настроить TabLayout так, чтобы вкладки растягивались на весь экран если есть свободное место, но если их много и они не помещаются, то TabLayout должен становиться скроллом, как при `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете переопределить разметку для разных экранов. Так же вы можете установить tabMode программно, исходя из количества табов или разрешения экрана `tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);`